# OpenCV CommandLineParser: how to detect bad arguments

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV's `CommandLineParser` ([doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d0/d2e/classcv_1_1CommandLineParser.html)) to parse arguments. I define a string `keys` with the desired command line flags. Is there any way to detect if an undefined flag is used? That is, I want to print an error if I run:

`myprogram --someUndefinedArgument`

The underlying problem is that if I have a typo in my arguments, my program continues fine, producing the wrong results. I want a way to detect this.

Comment: Did you try check: [https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d0/d2e/classcv_1_1CommandLineParser.html#ad6b244a52f3b90da6fc463341c8a486f](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d0/d2e/classcv_1_1CommandLineParser.html#ad6b244a52f3b90da6fc463341c8a486f)

Comment: @drescherjm, I use `check`, but it doesn't help. It complains if you try to access a missing argument, or an argument of the wrong type, but it doesn't care if the command line contains extra arguments.

Comment: I can't help with this functionality. I don't use the command line parser from opencv. With that said, I can give you a recommendation if you can't get this to work: [https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11)